# Android - DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString() does not work

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to insert "women's cloth" in the database, so I use

```
String name = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString("women's cloth");
```

but it gives out put like

```
"'Women''s Clothing'"
```

and while inserting app crashes and gives

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ",": syntax error
```

--------- beginning of crash -----------------

```
07-12 12:42:19.628 22387-22521/com.i4ustores E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8634
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1):
```

Comment: use \' for it . because in android you cant use directly ( ' ).

Comment: @VishalHalani A backslash is not an escape character in SQL.

Comment: Show the actual code.

Comment: thnx it works only api 23.

Comment: @ vishal halali below backslash works??

Answer (score 0):

From your simple code, I guess you create SQL statement manually.
Try using `String.format`:

```
String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = ?",
                      TABLE_NAME, SEARCH_KEY);
```

Read more at: [Local Databases with SQLiteOpenHelper](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper)

Or try using [PreparedStatement](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) like below:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES
                                     SET SALARY = ? WHERE ID = ?");
pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, 153833.00)
pstmt.setInt(2, 110592)
```

Please be aware that the **parameterIndex** (i.e 1 and 2 in above code) start from 1.

Comment: thanx...
but i use String.fromat() and this also not working for me

Comment: I forgot to tell to `not` using `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString` when trying with my answer.